# ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{SubString{String},1} at index [0]

Tags: julia

I wrote the following code:

```
for (count, x) in enumerate(["x1", "x1.y1", "x1.y1.xyz22", "x133001", "x133001.y1", "x133001.y1.xyz22"])
    print(x)
    print(" -> ") 
    println(count)
    split(x,".")[0]
end
```

in order to change the IDs from the left column to the right one:

```
x1                 -> 1
x1.y1              -> 1.y1 
x1.y1.xyz22        -> 1.y1.xyz22
...
x133001            -> 22
x133001.y1         -> 22.y1
x133001.y1.xyz22   -> 22.y1.xyz22
```

Unfortunately, I got `ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{SubString{String},1} at index [0]`.

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays in Julia are 1-based so it should be `split(x,".")[1]`